# The shapes of the USA map

Tags: geoserver, tiger, openstreetmap

I'm newbie in GIS.
I want use the shapefiles of USA map for my Geoserver. Where can I download shapes for USA? I know about the TIGER\Line shapes but it is separate shapes of counties and thematic maps (e.g. american indian areas). I want something like OpenStreetMap.
P.S. Sorry for my english )

Answer (score 7):

You can get polygon shapefiles of the US from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/. They cover the whole world.

Answer (score 4):

For just the state boundaries, you can [download data from data.gov](http://www.data.gov/geodata/g602028/). If you're interested in the actual OSM data, you can [download it at cloudmade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/usa), but it takes some processing to work with and is a fairly complex dataset.

Comment: Indian Lands too: http://www.data.gov/geodata/g602058/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to find the data for the native american people and much more on this site http://www.diva-gis.org/gData

@underdark: thanks for your link, i didnt know that site.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer comes with a US States layer by default. Look for http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp:states&styles=&bbox=-124.731,24.956,-66.97,49.372&width=780&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers if you have GeoServer running on your local machine.